# Create a new object on click

Tags: javascript, html, object

Good Day,
My question might be a bit 'newbie' but I am!
I have an object like this:

```
var person = {
   firstName: null, 
   lastName: null, 
   age: null, 
   eyeColor: null
};
```

So when I click a button to 'add' a new person (a new object), I would like to have something like this...

```
$("p").click(function(){
    var newPerson = new Person("John", "Doe", "50", "blue");
    console.log("A new person has been created!");
});
```

But this scenario is good for one object... How can I create 'many' new persons with different parameters, and especially different object names (var newPerson) ?
I know I can have a function with parameters, but the names of the objects remain the same, so the object is replaced by the new one...
I hope I'm clear... Or at least somebody will understand me! Thank You! :)

Comment: Use one array to store objects.

Comment: An array should work, but what would be the index for the array ?

Comment: Like : arr[x| = new Person(param1, param2, param3, param4); Every time I click on the button, x is not changing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the `var` keyword with the same label, it switches the object to which you're referring, so really the problem is finding a place to store your instances of the People class rather than creating different variable names. Something like this could work:

```
var people = [];

$("p").click(function(){
    var newPerson = new Person("John", "Doe", "50", "blue");
    people.push(newPerson);
    console.log("A new person has been created!");
});
```

This way, you can just refer to different people with the index at which they are stored in your `people` array.

`console.log(people[0]) //-> {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", age: 50, eyeColor: "blue"}`

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed !! Thank You ! :)

Comment: No problem! √√√

Answer (score -1):

I guess this will help you with your question:

HTML PART:

```
<form method="POST" id="form">
<input id="name" placeholder="First name"></input><br>
<input id="lname" placeholder="Last name"></input><br>
<input id="age" placeholder="Age"></input><br>
<input id="eye" placeholder="Eye Color"></input><br>
<button type="submit" id="btn">CREATE</button>
</form>
```

JS PART:

```
function person(f_name, l_name, age, eye_c) {
  this.fname = f_name;
  this.lname = l_name;
  this.age = age;
  this.eyec = eye_c; 
}  // Defining the object, consider it like a object template.
person.prototype.notif = function () {
    alert("The user with name " + this.fname + " logged in!");
    }  // Here is a function added outside the object, does not need to be done this way...It pops an alert box.

var id = 0; // ...so we can track the id/number of submits.
var list = []; // Here we will put all the entries, objects.
document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var name_value = document.getElementById("name").value; // Taking the value from the input field.
  var lname_value = document.getElementById("lname").value; // Taking the value from the input field.
  var age_value = document.getElementById("age").value; // Taking the value from the input field.
  var eye_value = document.getElementById("eye").value; // Taking the value from the input field.
  list[id] = new person(name_value, lname_value, age_value, eye_value); // Making the new object of name list with an ID ( list0, list1... )
  list[id].notif();  // Giving the notification...
  id++;  // Increasing the ID afther every submit, so we can track the list.
  console.log(list);
};  // Creating the new object (could be new acc for example), with the entered parameters.
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation to go along with the code?